# Can I make a linked server for Oracle on a SQL Server which are installed with both 32 bit and 64 bit drivers?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Although I can see a link server which I made on my SQL Server (SSMS), but can't use it.
I actually got a message failing to connect by `OraOLEDB.Oracle` in process of creating the linked server.

As everyone said, I have already done the setting that the Inprocess on the provider is allowed.

My concern is that the x64 windows server has been installed both 32bit and 64 bit driver to connect other Oracle Database server.

The server is also installed SSDT which is 32bit application. Because we need to develop some Integration packages(SSIS) on the same server.

If someone could create a link server on the same situation, could you tell me how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: How did you install the 32bit and 64bit driver? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: I have to applogize to everyone. I could make a linked sever on our SQL Server just before.
The problem I faced seemed to be diffrent from what I inquiried here. I am very sorry.

Migrating Windwos Server 2016 to Windows Server 2019, I was using a script generated on the Old server to create a linked serer.

I shouldn't have trusted the script too much. The security information does not take over apprently.
When I operated by handle on SSMS, It have smoothly created the linked server.